# Raku multiplication using prompt and say

Tags: raku

I have extensively consulted Raku documentation and have tried many combinations to finally arrive at this working solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl6
use v6;

my $a;
my $b = 34;
my $c;
$a = prompt "enter number: ";
$c = ($a * $b);
say  "$a multiplied by  $b is $c";
```

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the community! CodeReview.SE is to ask for peer reviews of code that is _working as intended_! For help with problems in your code, like the ones you seem to be exhibiting, you are better off [asking at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) :)

Comment: @AlexV The flawed code wasn't reviewed, so I threw it out and left the working code it. That should take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

To tighten your code a bit, you can declare `my $a` and assign in the same line:

```
my $a = prompt "enter number: ";
my $b = 34;
my $c;
$c = ($a * $b);
say  "$a multiplied by  $b is $c";
```

The above seems to solve your question, however a user might not respond with the proper input. If a user replies to the prompt with `Hello` you'll get an ungraceful error:

```
Cannot convert string to number: base-10 number must begin with valid digits or '.' in '⏏Hello' (indicated by ⏏) in block <unit> at Pedr_Ap_Glyn.p6 line 7
```

You can add a Type declaration to obviate this issue:

```
my Int $a = prompt "enter number: ";
```

...which, if an `Int` is not returned, will error with the message:

```
Type check failed in assignment to $a; expected Int but got [WHAT RAKU GOT IS HERE] in block <unit> at Pedr_Ap_Glyn.p6 line 5
```

Maybe a different pre-declared Type is more useful for your case:

```
my Numeric $a = prompt "enter number: ";
```

...which will work with non-Integer input (e.g. `3.14159265`).

Or you could declare your own Type subset (below, "PosInt"):

```
subset PosInt of Int where * > 0;
my PosInt $a = prompt "enter number: ";
```

...which will only accept `Int`s greater that zero. Above are just a few options that the Raku language offers--and that you may wish to take advantage of.